# Popup above action bar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-actionbar, popup

I'm trying to align the popup to under the action bar and I don't find any solution, I already seen some videos and nothing, please help me, I'm starting to program and I'm really noob at this, here is my print screen of the problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdHDx.png

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView webview;
private static final String TAG = "Main";
private ProgressDialog progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

    WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "android");
    webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

    progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Gear Track", "Loading...");

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
            Log.i(TAG, "Processing webview url click...");
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
            Log.i(TAG, "Finished loading url: " +url);
            if (progressBar.isShowing()){
                progressBar.dismiss();
            }
        }
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + description);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
            alertDialog.setMessage(description);
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
    webview.loadUrl("https://geartrack.hdn.pt");
}
public class WebAppInterface{
    Context mContext;

    WebAppInterface(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast){
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){

        case R.id.action_refresh:
            webview.loadUrl("https://geartrack.hdn.pt");
            return true;

        case R.id.action_about:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, About.class));
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webview.canGoBack()){
        webview.goBack();
        return true;
    }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }
}
```

Xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:checkable="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_name"
    android:title="Refresh"
    android:visible="true"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_about"
    android:title="About"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```